# Add a sequential number in a particular line for multiple files

Tags: command

Can somebody tell me the command to add a sequential number to a particular line in a file and increment the same to other files.

Ex:
I have 5 files (messages)
In line  5 of each message file, I wanted to add incremental sequential number like as Subject: 1 , Subject: 2, Subject: 3 ... Sample output should be as below.

```
File1: line5: Subject: **1** message
File2: line5: Subject: **2** message
File3: line5: Subject: **3** message
File4: line5: Subject: **4** message
File5: line5: Subject: **5** message
```

Comment: Are the messages _email messages_ and can you guarantee that the subject line is always on line 5?

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below command and worked fine

```
for i in 5; do sed -i ''$i'i subject '$i'' file1;j=$(($i+1)); sed -i  ''$i'i subject '$j'' file2;k=$(($j+1)); sed -i ''$i'i subject '$k' ' file3;l=$(($k+1));sed -i ''$i'i subject '$l'' file4;m=$(($l+1)); sed -i ''$i'i subject '$m'' file5;done
```

Comment: Thanks for the input .. but i have 500k files

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `perl`:

```
perl -pi -e 's/^Subject: \K/sprintf("%05d ", ++$n)/e' File*
```

Would add an incremented number (0 padded to width 5) after each occurrence of `Subject:` at the beginning of a line.

For the first occurrence only:

```
perl -pi -e '
  unless ($found_already) {
    $found_already = 1 if s/^Subject: \K/sprintf("%05d ", ++$n)/e
  }
  $found_already = 0 if eof' File*
```

To prepend `Subject: <increasing-number>` to line 5 of each file:

```
perl -pi -e '$_ = sprintf("Subject: %05d %s", ++$n, $_) if $. == 5; 
             close ARGV if eof' File*
```

Note that the files are given to perl in the order decided by the shell's glob expansion. With most shells, that's lexical order. If the file names are numbered without padding, that means `File10` will come before `File2`. With the `zsh` shell, you can replace `File*` with `File*(n)` for the list to be numerically sorted or `File*(Om)` for it to be sorted by age of the file (from the oldest to the youngest).

Comment: 'Thanks for the command and it worked actually. But only issue what i see here is --> There is no space i could get for the next word to sequential number.

Ex: I tried adding for 3 files (using: perl -pi -e 's/^Subject: \K/++$n/e' 1-f-*.eml) and it added the number. But no space between number and next words.'

Comment: `Current output:
=================
Subject: 1sequence test
Subject: 2Thanks for the command
Subject: 3need a little more change
    :
    :
Subject: 500000for 5lakh files`

Comment: `Expecetd output:
================
Subject: 000001 sequence test
Subject: 000002 Thanks for the command
Subject: 000003 need a little more change
    :
    :
Subject: 500000 for 5lakh files`

Comment: @SateeshKumar, see edit

Comment: Thanks a lot .. working .. really helpful ..

Comment: Can this script be restricted only to add sequence for the first occurrence of "Subject:"    or only one sequence number to be added per file  ... because in some of my files i have multiple times we get "Subject:" in different lines. Hence its adding the sequence there also. Ex: if i have 10 files and each file have two lines as subject:  ..... in last file i see sequence number updated as line5: Subject:19   , Line10: Subject:20  .. instead i should see only Subject:10 in last file.  because of this its not serving my purpose.

Comment: @SateeshKumar, see edit.

Comment: Thanks .. it worked ...appreciate all your help

Comment: @SateeshKumar Good! If this solves your issue, please consider ["accepting" the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). This is the best way to show gratitude on this site.  Accepting an answer not only marks the question as resolved, but also signals to _future readers_ that the accepted answer actually solved the issue.  More information about this is available here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers